# Shard resources by thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a (limited) thread pool which executes CPU-bound tasks.  I'd like to aggregate some numerical statistics from each of these threads in a single place.  Basically: each thread will update some shared stats (e.g. how long its job took) at a very high frequency and, at some much slower interval, a 'stat reader' would query those stats.

My first thought was to use some shared atomics and update them from each thread.  This works ok, but in my testing the overhead of the atomics can get pretty high with a lot of contention so I was trying to think of some other alternatives.

My second though was a sort of 'sharding' scheme, where each thread had its own stats object that it could update without requiring any synchronization.  The 'stat reader' could then aggregate the stats from each thread into an overall stat value.

My first question is: does the thread sharding scheme make sense? Does something like that exist that I'm reinventing?

My second question is: if the sharding scheme does make sense, I'm trying to think of the best way to map threads to their shard:

1) Use the thread's ID mod some shard value to get a shard index, but I don't think that's reliable as I think the thread id value is shared, so I could get a collision.

2) Adding a thread-local index to the thread, but I don't think that will play nicely with the ExecutorService.

3) I could subclass Thread, but then I'd have to cast it when I wanted to access this which I'd rather avoid, if possible.

4) When the thread is created, create a mapping of its name to its shard.  This would work, but there would be a race when creating the threads: one could be looking up its shard while we're adding a new shard to the map, causing concurrency issues.

Wondering if I'm way off-base here and overthinking it (seems like it would be a common problem?) or if one of these schemes does make sense for the use case.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a proper monitoring tool like Prometheus.

Comment: You said "each thread had its own stats object that it could update without requiring any synchronization". Since the stat-reader will access that stats object, the thread will need to update that object synchronizing it.

Comment: @RobertKock the thinking was that since the stat reader is just reading the values (and I don't care about performing the read of all stats atomically) I could avoid the synchronization there.

Comment: thanks @daniu, I'll look more into Prometheus.

Comment: As I've tested on Java 12, an own atomic counter per thread is the most efficient way.

It's better to clarify the expected amount of the running processes and how often each thread make the updates. Do you have particular given numeric conditions?

Comment: @edwgiz, you don't even need to use an atomic counter per thread since the updates are single-threaded per counter. A `volatile` will suffice in that case. Just have to be careful that the counters are not sharing a cacheline.

Comment: @Eric
I have similar case in one of my projects, atomics are 2-3 times more efficient than volatile fields

Comment: @edwgiz, that might be true for just your specific case but there's nothing in general that says atomics are faster than volatiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use the `LongAdder` class that avoids the contention that plain old atomics suffer from.

A more hand-written approach would be to create some class that holds the statistics you want to gather for each thread, and then have an array of these objects such that each thread's stats object is in `array[thread.getId() % NUM_THREADS]`. The reader thread can then traverse the array and gather the stats as it pleases.

The trick to getting this to work efficiently is to avoid [false sharing](https://dzone.com/articles/false-sharing-cache-coherence-and-the-contended-an). That is, threads on different cores perform updates on their respective objects but those objects happen to reside on the same cacheline, causing massive amounts of unnecessary cache coherence traffic.

In Java 8, there is the `@Contended` annotation that you might want to look into. The old way of padding your class with a bunch of `long` fields doesn't work anymore since unused fields will be optimized away.

Comment: Thanks, Eric, `LongAdder` looks like it may be exactly what I need.  The hand-written approach you describe is the path I was going down, but it appears that `LongAdder` will achieve the same thing and won't rely on extra code I have to write :)

Comment: And thanks for the link to false sharing (since I may have some stats that `LongAdder` may not be appropriate for).  I think I'd be alright there as I had the entire stats 'instance' allocated to each thread, so I won't have a situation of multiple threads updating different (consecutive) stat values in the same instance.  That should avoid the false sharing problem, is that right?

Comment: @bbaldino, do you mean that each thread has its own stats instance (i.e. a `ThreadLocal`)?

Comment: Not a thread local, but an instance held in an array which is indexed by a unique index assigned to each thread (that way I can also access all of them via the 'reader' thread)

Comment: @bbaldino, in that case, you are going to have to make sure each instance fills a cacheline. The article I linked to mentions how to do this.

Comment: Ok, I think I see.  Is that true because even though I'm accessing fields in separate `Stat` instances, I'm using an ArrayList--so a continuous chunk of memory?

Comment: Sorry, I thought too quickly there. Each reference in the array will reside contiguously but the actual instances are allocated individually on the heap. Whether or not some instances happen to share a cacheline is dependent on the JVM implementation, garbage collection, underlying architecture, etc. You might still want to pad your object so it fills an entire cacheline though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use different way: `Actor`.

> The actor model provides a relatively simple but powerful model for designing and implementing applications that can **distribute and share work across all system resources—from threads and cores to clusters of servers and data centers**. It provides an effective framework for building applications with high levels of concurrency and for increasing levels of resource efficiency. Importantly, the actor model also has well-defined ways for handling errors and failures gracefully, ensuring a level of resilience that isolates issues and prevents cascading failures and massive downtime.

You can turn to [Akka](https://akka.io/) i think.

Comment: You're talking about using an actor and storing the stats object there?  That could be interesting and there are other aspects of using actors which I think could be nice, but it would be a bigger change and might not fit into the timeframe I had in mind for these stats, unfortunately.